# Dynamic urls based on username rather than UID - Friendly PIx demo

Tags: firebase

I'm new to firebase and like what i've seen so far!

Currently i'm trying to use the friendly Pix example as a base for my Firebase Web app using angularjs but I wanted users to be able to search for other users via the url with a different structure using their username rather than the UID to identify them. E.g:

Currently the URL structure is https://friendly-pix.com/user/08VdUeDOkhNgHXjaT2w77u9czM03

I was looking to change it to something like https://friendly-pix.com/user/SomeUsername